# Firebase child_changed event misses randomly, if browser tab is idle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am building real-time app where one person is entering in app and all the connected users of that session are getting noticed or receiving payload what a person is entering.

Following is my firebase child_changed listener which every device is listening to:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('collection')
    .orderByChild('sessionId')
    .equalTo('123') //unique id
    .on('child_changed', function (snapshot) {
    //some processing                 
});
```

Whenever a person enters in app i update above firebase document/collection like this:

```
var newObject = {},
        fbId = 'Kh8nyd9C1FGeBx229ogyr';// unique id of document to be updated

newObject[fbId] = {
    'sessionId': '123',
    'payLoad': JSON.stringify(payLoad), //different payload to send to each device which is listening to collection and this session
    'lastUpdated': new Date().getTime() //adding unique time so child_changed should trigger
};

firebase.database().ref().child('collection').update(newObject);

//rules

"rules": {
    "$uid": {
        "collection": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
                    ".indexOn": ["sessionlId"]
        }  
    }
}

//data

{
  "Azublidegytttsbmnmnmnm": { //uid
    "collection": {
      "Kh8nyd9C1FGeBx229ogyr": {
        "sessionId": 123,
        "payLoad": {Id: '11', Name: 'John Doe'},
        "lastUpdated": 1543875382963 
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

The above code works most of the times but misses events if browser tab stays idle for sometime and then it stops receving this event or not able to trigger child_changed event if a person who's entering has entered and the other connected person's tab is idle. I refresh browser firebase connect code gets refreshed and now things work correctly.

Any help is appreciated regarding firing this child_changed event each time. Or please suggest any other approach for catering this issue.

My firebase lib is 3.5.3 version.

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds pretty unexpected, and your listener looks fine. Is the write performed by the same client that listens? Also: can you [capture the detailed debug log](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database#.enableLogging) when the problem occurs? Finally: any chance you can set up a repro in a site like jsbin, so I can have a look?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Yes who ever enters write to same session collection so that all connected devices listen and get the updated payload.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: Also it usually happens when multiple nodes are being listened by multiple users. Let's say 30 users are listening to this Kh8nyd9C1FGeBx229ogyr and another 10 users are listening to second node Kh8reCq1FGeBx229ogzx and so on. We have a firebase plan as you go. So user restriction is not issue here. I can't create/replicate scenario on jsbin or jsfiddle which i am facing in real. Please suggest any solution. My firebase lib is very old should i switch to latest lib?

Comment: In that case sharing the debug output from the client when the problem occurs is the best way forward.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen if the source who's writing to Json collection  doesn't have stable connection to firebase then all the connected devices listening to child_changed event miss receiving this payload or event. This is what happening. Can you please tell solution to avoid? What is the network requirements for connecting to firebase? Thanks sir any help is appreciated.

Comment: Once the data is written to the server, it will be synchronized to all connected clients. But I'm still unclear on what's going on, and your descriptions are unfortunately not helping. Without a debug log, or clearer code that I can use to reproduce the problem with, it'll be impossible to say much more.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am sorry if i am not explaining correctly :(. Let me try again let say I am entering in app i don't have a stable connection firebase does everything on local if internet is not working correctly? right? And as soon as it gets healthy connection it syncs data to live db. So a user who is entering and seeing changes via his localStorage logic implemented by firebase. This data doesnot reach live db and other devices which are listening to child_changed dont get payload what this user is entering.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen On a stable connection everything works like a charm and above code works perfectly. The only issue is where network has slight problem then it starts to happen. Sir can I talk to in private my email id is osamammursleen@gmail.com and skypeid: osamammursleen. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry to bug you again. I have added just one user through which all connected devices communicate with firebase. My rules are like:
"rules": {
    "$uid": {
      "collection": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
          ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
          ".indexOn": ["sessionlId"]
    }  
 }
}
And my data is like:
{
  "Azublidegytttsbmnmnmnm": { //uid
    "collection": {
      "Kh8nyd9C1FGeBx229ogyr": {
        "sessionId": 123,
        "payLoad": {Id: '11', Name: 'John Doe'},
        "lastUpdated": 1543875382963 
      }
    }  
  }
}

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen: http://jsfiddle.net/rqs48dm3/ rules and data demonstration. All devices get this uid and username from api and log in with same user when communicate with firebase. Can this be a problem? I am using firebase just for listening events and receiving real data across devices. Ideally each user who is connecting with firebase should have his own sign-in. BUT i just only created master user and avoided that. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Since the jsfiddle doesn't run, you may just as well add the data to the question. But I'm still most interested in the debug log output that I asked for in my first comment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Debugging is okay and i can see firebase stays connected. JSFiddle is just for you to see my rules json and my sample data which i am writing or listening.

Comment: Have you tried using a process manager like pm2 or forever to restart the process? If you are doing it on the browser, I would suggest you add a listener to [onDisconnect](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#how-ondisconnect-works) to have a fallback mechanism

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated my firebase 3.5.3 to latest. And I have started to bind the event directly at node instead of listening to whole json collection (was listening at root).

OLD CODE:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('collection')
    .orderByChild('sessionId')
    .equalTo('123') //unique id
    .on('child_changed', function (snapshot) {
    //some processing                 
});
```

NEW CODE:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('collection/Kh8nyd9C1FGeBx229ogyr') //Kh8nyd9C1FGeBx229ogyr here is firebase generated node and its unique id
    .on('child_changed', function (snapshot) {
    //some processing                 
});
```

P.S Try listening to the lowest level to get the child_changed event. 
From Firebase support